# Best practices - 2 Method with same functionality - one throws exception and another suppress

Tags: java, exception, coding-style, overloading

As it doesn't make sense to overload methods based on the exception clause.
Most of the times when we are writing the code, we came into a scenario where

- we want some piece of code to throw an exception so that we can handle it accordingly
- some times for the same piece of code we just want to ignore that exception

Example below -

```
// It is used at many places and we just want to take specific action if any exception is coming,
// like retry if SQLExceptions
private List<Contact> getContacts() throws Exceptions{                 
    List<Contact> contacts = null;
    try {
        contacts = contactDao.getContacts();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        logger(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

---

```
    private List<Contact> getContacts1() throws Exceptions{                 
        List<Contact> contacts = null;
        try {
            contacts = contactDao.getContacts();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger(ex);
        }
        return contacts;
    }
// It is used at some places and I want this method to throw an exception, 
// I want to handle it using null check
```

What should be the correct ways to write such methods.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should have two methods since they'd do different things inside.

For example, at ROR, there is a convention to handle your problem. When methods are finished with a `!` means that if something goes wrong an exception will be raised. So, when you want to save an item you can call

- `save!`: it raises an exception if the item can't be saved or returns the item itself
- or `save`: it doesn't raise anything and returns true or false according to the state of the operation

I'm not sure which language you are coding but maybe it could be helpful to find your language convention. If there is no convention at your current language/framework you could define one with your team and use it internally. For example, you can define a `getContacts_unsafe` method ann know that suffix means it doesn't raise an exception